# What are the pre installed packages in the Google Cloud Dataflow worker Python runtime environments?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I couldn't find the list of pre installed packages in the Google Cloud Dataflow worker instances. Is it documented somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python

> IMPORTANT: The Google Cloud virtual machines (i.e.workers) used for
>   pipeline execution have a standard Python 2.7 distribution installed
>   on them. If your code relies only on standard Python packages, then
>   you don't need to do anything mentioned on this page.

Comment: The link changed

Answer (score 0):

This information can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies

It would be cool if this list were available in a more machine-readable form, so it could be used for filtering the contents of a job's `requirements.txt`.